# Multiple query strings parameter handling in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We are developing ADB2C custom policies to handle the user authentication and registration requests coming from the client web app.

I have a scenario, our web application is  redirecting login / signup requests to B2C and that requests url append with a couple of query string parameters for ex:- userName=“John”&webApp=37658.  Now, the expectation is to return those query string parameters via b2c JWT token once that user flow execution is completed in b2c. Is there helpful references to handle these scenario via b2c custom policies ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [claims resolvers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview#oauth2-key-value-parameters) to get the values and then add them as output claims in the JWT.

Comment: How to handle a different query string parameters in the b2c login / signup request url coming from the browser via b2c custom Policies?